# How do I configure the server so that It stores the dynamically created files in the specified folder not under the bin folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have developed a web application which will create an xml file based on the user Input. It has some more functionality. I configured my application to store the xml file(s) in the project root folder. When I run it through eclipse It stores in the specified location. But If I manually put the war file in apache tomcat and run the application those newly created xml files are going into bin directory since I used relative path. Now I dont want it to be created under bin directory. I want those files to be created somewhere local in the system. Is there any way to do it ? Or else what is the best way to deal with those xml files. I am using spring MVC.

Comment: So use absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable in your code would contain the first part of the path (the real location where you want to write the file). And inject the value of that variable from a properties file, that way you wouldn't hardcode anything, and still would be able to provide only the relative path in your code.